I'm on a java spring boot ticket project if 2 user buy the same seat id the faster one can go to payment page and the other one will receive alert
i have heard about using web socket but i don't understand it clearly on my html when i click , can get the json of full seat and its attributes. It also tell me that i connected to websocket success but the config of web socket makes me rather confusing with all the link should i think that i need to replace the link but what should i put in it though
here are my controller
@GetMapping("/concert/xem/{id}/map")
    public String getMap(Model model, @PathVariable int id) {

        Concert concert = concertService.getConcertById(id);
        List<Seat> seats = concertService.getSeatsByConcertId(id);
        List<Zone> listZone = zoneService.getAllZones();
        List<ConcertZone> concertZoneList = concertZoneService.getConcertZonesByConcertId(id);

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE d MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formattedStartDate = concert.getStartDate().format(formatter);

        model.addAttribute("concert", concert);
        model.addAttribute("concertZones", concertZoneList);
        model.addAttribute("seats", seats);
        model.addAttribute("listZone", listZone);
        model.addAttribute("formattedStartDate", formattedStartDate);

        model.addAttribute("content", "user/html/seatmap.html");

        return "layout.html";
    }
@PostMapping("/concert/payment")
public String handlePayment(@RequestBody Map<String, List<Integer>> requestBody, HttpSession session) {
    
    List<Integer> seatIds = requestBody.get("seatIds");

    if (seatIds == null || seatIds.isEmpty()) {
        return "errorPage"; 
    }

    
    session.setAttribute("selectedSeatIds", seatIds);

    return "redirect:/concert/payment";  
}

@GetMapping("/concert/payment")
public String showPaymentPage(HttpSession session, Model model) {
   
    List<Integer> seatIds = (List<Integer>) session.getAttribute("selectedSeatIds");

    if (seatIds == null || seatIds.isEmpty()) {
        return "errorPage";  
    }


    List<Seat> listSeat = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer seatId : seatIds) {
        
        Seat seat = seatService.findById(seatId);
        if (seat != null) {
            listSeat.add(seat);
        }
    }

    double totalAmount = listSeat.stream()
        .mapToDouble(Seat::getPrice)  // Lấy giá tiền của từng ghế
        .sum();  // Tính tổng

    
    model.addAttribute("totalAmount", totalAmount);   
    model.addAttribute("listSeat", listSeat);
    return "user/html/payment";  
}

my websocket config
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
    public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    
        @Override
        public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
            config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
            config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        }
    
        @Override
        public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
            registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
        }
    }

and my html :
<div class="seat-map-body" style="height: 491px;">
                            <div th:fragment="seats">
                                <div id="seats">
                                    <div th:each="row : ${#numbers.sequence(1, 40)}" class="seat-row">
                                        <div th:each="seat : ${seats}" th:if="${seat.seat_row == row}" style="margin: 0.5rem;">
                                            <div th:if="${seat.status}">
                                                <i class="fas fa-couch"
                                                th:style="|color: ${seat.booked ? 'red' : seat.getColor()}|"
                                                th:id="'seat-' + ${seat.id}"
                                                th:onclick="if (![[${seat.booked}]]) { selectSeat([[${seat.id}]], [[${seat.seat_row}]], [[${seat.seat_column}]], [[${seat.status}]], [[${seat.getPrice()}]]) }"
                                                th:classappend="${seat.booked ? 'disabled' : ''}"
                                                th:attr="style=${seat.booked ? 'cursor: not-allowed; pointer-events: none;' : 'cursor: pointer; pointer-events: auto;'}">
                                                </i>
                                            </div>
                                            <div th:if="${!seat.status}" style="display: inline-block; width: 2.3rem; height: 1.5rem;"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
<script>
    let selectedSeats = [];
    let totalPrice = 0;
    const maxSeats = 4;  // Maximum number of seats allowed

    function selectSeat(seatId, seatRow, seatColumn, seatStatus, seatPrice) {
        const seatElement = document.getElementById("seat-" + seatId);
        const seatLabel = `${seatRow}-${seatColumn}`; // Format row-column

        if (selectedSeats.some(seat => seat.id === seatId)) {
            // If the seat is already selected, unselect it and revert to original color
            selectedSeats = selectedSeats.filter(seat => seat.id !== seatId);
            seatElement.classList.remove("selected");
            seatElement.style.color = seatStatus ? seatElement.getAttribute("data-original-color") : "red";
            totalPrice -= seatPrice; // Subtract the seat price from the total
        } else {
            // If the seat is not selected, check if the maximum limit is reached
            if (selectedSeats.length >= maxSeats) {
                alert(`You can only select up to ${maxSeats} seats.`);
                return;  // Prevent selecting more than the allowed number of seats
            }

            // Select the seat and change its color to black
            selectedSeats.push({ id: seatId, label: seatLabel, price: seatPrice });
            seatElement.classList.add("selected");
            seatElement.setAttribute("data-original-color", seatElement.style.color); // Store original color
            seatElement.style.color = "black"; // Change color to black
            totalPrice += seatPrice; // Add the seat price to the total
        }

        // Update the list of selected seats displayed in "row-column" format
        const selectedSeatLabels = selectedSeats.map(seat => seat.label).join(", ");
        document.getElementById("seat_selected").innerText = selectedSeatLabels;

        // Update the total price display
        document.getElementById("price_selected").innerText = totalPrice.toLocaleString();

        // Save the selected seat IDs to sessionStorage
        const selectedSeatIds = selectedSeats.map(seat => seat.id);
        sessionStorage.setItem('selectedSeatIds', JSON.stringify(selectedSeatIds));

        console.log("Selected seats: ", selectedSeats); // Check the selected seats
    }

    function bookSeats() {
        // Get the selected seat IDs from sessionStorage
        const selectedSeatIds = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('selectedSeatIds'));
    
        if (selectedSeatIds) {
            // Send a POST request with the selected seat data
            fetch('/concert/payment', {
                method: 'POST',  // Ensure the POST method is used
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ seatIds: selectedSeatIds }),  // Send the data in the body
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Server error: ' + response.statusText);
                }
                return response.text(); // Handle the response data
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log("Server response:", data);
                // After receiving the data, you can redirect to the payment page
                window.location.href = "/concert/payment";
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error("Error while sending POST request:", error);
            });
        } else {
            console.error("No seats selected!");
        }
    }
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sockjs-client/1.4.0/sockjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stomp.js/2.3.3/stomp.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const socket = new SockJS('/ws-seat');
    const stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

    stompClient.connect({}, function () {
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/seatStatus', function (message) {
            const seatUpdate = JSON.parse(message.body);
            const seatElement = document.getElementById('seat-' + seatUpdate.seatId);
            if (seatUpdate.booked) {
                seatElement.classList.add('disabled');
                seatElement.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
                seatElement.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
            }
        });
    });
</script>

